# recursively extract each individual list from nested list python

Tags: python, append, nested-lists, object-slicing

not a python expert. I have a nested list like

```
result=[["a","b","c"],["d","e","f"],["g","h","i"], ...]
```

I would like to obtain separated lists for each sub list:

```
sublist1=["a","b","c"]
sublist2=["d","e","f"]
sublist3=["g","h","i"]
...
```

I know the "manual" procedure slicing using indexes, problem is that I have  20000 sublists and I am looking for a way to do that recursively and store the result in 20000 different list that are created automatically.

My current guess was to use a for loop like

```
for d in range(0, len(result)):
```

in order to have all the 20000 indexes, and than use slicing with theses indexes.
Problem is that I have no idea of how to generate 20000 empty lists where to store each result in a way that is not manual.
There are probably other alterntaives, but I could not think of anything that excluded rewriting the same command 20000 times.

Answer (score 0):

```
result=[["a","b","c"],["d","e","f"],["g","h","i"]]
result_dict ={}
serial = 1
for inner_list in result:
    sub_list_name ="sublist"+str(serial) 
    serial = serial + 1
    result_dict[sub_list_name] = inner_list
print(result_dict)
```

I have used an unorderedDict incase order matters you can use orderedDict.

Comment: Thanks, good alternative that creates a dictionary with keys that progressively increase in number.